# callback sms url response from twilio

Tags: php, codeigniter, twilio

Im getting successfully twilio sms with callback url.My doubt is im want to echo the accsid.After successfully send i use to get callback in smsifo.php file. Here i use to get like this in below.

```
SmsSid=SMa535b23ebc9d40bba20bcd14ecd56e0a&SmsStatus=delivered&MessageStatus=delivered&To=%2B9123456&MessageSid=SMa535b23ebc9d40bba20bcd14ecd56e0a&AccountSid=AC32f5f7f3d15aed8355ded367a518652a&From=%2B13342125464&ApiVersion=2010-04-01.<br>
```

All i want SmsSid only 
and i tried like this also

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['SmsSid'])) { 
echo 'SmsSid'; 
}else{ 
echo 'nthg';
 }   ?>
```

Comment: What do you get at the moment?

Comment: i did in this way file_put_contents('input.txt',$_POST['SmsSid'].'---'.$_POST['SmsStatus']);  im getting the output as what i have been expecting

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what it is you are trying to do or what is not working.